# Demonstration of inequality for angular momentum in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

I am stuck in this quantum mechanics exercise, it goes like this:

> Imposing the condition
>   $\int (\hat{L}_{\pm} Y_l^m)^\dagger (\hat{L}_{\pm} Y_l^m ) d \Omega = 0$. 
>   Show that $l(l+1) \ge m^2 \pm m $.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) We are not simply a homework help site, so it would be nice if you would show what you have done so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Recall that 
\begin{align}
   \hat{L}_{\pm} Y_{l}^{m} = \hbar  \sqrt{ l(l+1) - m(m \pm 1) } \, Y_{l}^{m \pm 1}
\end{align}

Comment: Well, I was trying this,  but I was getting an equality.  I think it must be a typo error from the book.  Thank you very much